# After executing query, values are not being imported into Access

Tags: java, ms-access

I am trying to insert values into Ms access database .The table has 4 fields there is no primary key also the 4 fields are number type.When i am trying to execute the following java code using prepared statement:

```
DatabaseConnection dbcon=new DatabaseConnection();

Connection con=dbcon.dbconnection();
String query="INSERT INTO test2 VALUES(?,?,?,?)";
PreparedStatement ps= con.prepareStatement(query);
ps.setInt(1, 1);
ps.setInt(2, 2);
ps.setInt(3, 3);
ps.setInt(4, 4);
ps.executeUpdate();
```

Query executed successfully but table2 does not displays values.

Comment: I am trying to execute simple insert query using 'MS ACCESS' query wizard but still values are not inserted into table

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There wasn't any issue with Connection.
I Was not Closing ResultSet and Connection object thats why the Problem Occured.

Answer (score 1):

Check your database connection likes this,

```
    String dataSourceName = "mdbTEST";
    String dbURL = "jdbc:odbc:" + dataSourceName;
    try { 
         Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
         Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, "",""); 
   } catch (Exception err) {
        System.out.println( "Error: " + err );
   }
```

If the connection is not OK, you may be set up a Data Source Name on your system.Try the following steps.

1. In Windows,choose Start > Settings > Control Panel > Administrative Tools > Data Sources.
2. In the ODBC Data Source Administrator dialog box, click the System DSN tab.
3. Click Add to add a new DSN to the list.
4. Scroll down and select the Microsoft Access (.MDB) driver
5. Type in the name "mdbTEST" (no quotes, but leave the cases the same) for the Data Source Name
6. Click CREATE and select a file to save the database to (I choose "D:\java\mdbTEST.mdb") - this creates a new blank MS Access database!
   Click "ok" all the way out Now our data source is done!